# Checking the frequency of numbers throughout an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code which I'm trying to use to show how many times a certain number appears throughout the array. I want it to print out how many times it counted a specific number. (all numbers range from 0-20, with an index of 0 - 99).

```
 void count_frequency(int *number) {
  int i;
  int j;
  int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int);
  printf("%i\n", len);
  printf("reached here");
  for(i = 0; i < 99; i++){ //index{
    int c = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 99; j++){
      if(number[j] == number[i]){
        c++;
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }

  printf("%i\n", c);
   //printf("%i\n", number[i]);
   }
}



int main(){
  int i;
  int table[MAX];
  int len = sizeof table / sizeof(int);
  printf("%ireached before loop\n", len);

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        table[i] = random_in_range(0, 20); 
  }
  count_frequency(table);
  //printf("%i", sizeof(table) / sizeof(int));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Congratulations - you have code.  What's the question?

Comment: Probably `i<100`, `j<100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int);
```

will not going to give you what you are expecting. `number` is a pointer variable not an array. Change your function to

```
void count_frequency(int *number, int len) {
     int i;
     int j;
     int index[21] = {0};
     printf("%i\n", len);
     printf("reached here");
     for(i = 0; i < len; i++){ //index{
          index[number[i]%21]++;
     }
     for(i = 0; i < 21; i++)
         printf("%d", index[i]);
}
```

and your function call should be

```
count_frequency(table, len);
```

Comment: @Floris; OK. Now its of order `n` (O(n)).

Comment: Just to be safe, don't increment for numbers greater than 20. I did this with a `%21` operation; you could just ignore those numbers. But if you don't check your input... you know what happens.

Comment: There. Now it looks a lot like my answer, so I can upvote at last.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. Honestly there was some magical thinking in your code. This works - it's not "the best" but an improvement on what you had. Let me know if this isn't clear. My definition of `rand_in_range` is not completely accurate - it will bias very slightly towards lower numbers.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100
#define random_in_range(a,b) ( rand() % ((b) - (a) + 1) + (a) )

void count_frequency(int *table, int *output, int n1, int n2) {
// n1 = number of elements in table
// n2 = number of elements in output
  int i;
//  int len = sizeof number / sizeof(int); <<<< meaningless!
//  printf("%i\n", len);
//  printf("reached here");
  for(i = 0; i < n1; i++) { // loop over the elements in the table
    output[table[i] %n 2]++;  // using % n2 so we don't go outside bounds of array.
    }
}

int main(){
  int i;
  int table[MAX];
  int counts[21]={0};  // <<<< need a place to put the result
  int len = sizeof table / sizeof(int);

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        table[i] = random_in_range(0, 20);
  }

  count_frequency(table, counts, MAX, 21);

  for(i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
     printf("number %d - frequency %d\n", i, counts[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
number 0 - frequency 3
number 1 - frequency 5
number 2 - frequency 3
number 3 - frequency 6
number 4 - frequency 6
number 5 - frequency 7
number 6 - frequency 3
number 7 - frequency 5
number 8 - frequency 6
number 9 - frequency 9
number 10 - frequency 4
number 11 - frequency 2
number 12 - frequency 6
number 13 - frequency 8
number 14 - frequency 3
number 15 - frequency 4
number 16 - frequency 5
number 17 - frequency 6
number 18 - frequency 6
number 19 - frequency 3
number 20 - frequency 0
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Right again... fixed (I think).

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying you have an array of 100 numbers, each ranging from 0-20, and you want to count the occurrences of a SINGLE number within that array?  Then this should do:

```
size_t count_occurrences(int interesting_num, int* array, size_t array_size) {
    size_t i, occurrences = 0;

    for (i=0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        if (array[array_size] == interesting_num) {
            ++occurrences;
        }
    }

    return occurrences;
}
```

Technically, you could replace those "size_t"s with unsigned chars, for the number ranges you're talking about, but given the dynamic calculation of len that you attempted, and the use of "MAX", I suspect you may want to increase those ranges at some point.  So, I'm erring on the side of a safer, more general implementation.